# MDB connection to MySQL Database in Lazarus (free Pascal)

Tags: mysql-connector, lazarus

I am trying to read a .mdb file and populate a new table in an existing MySQL server. I keep getting this same error everytime:[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di5L1.png)
and I just don't know what else to do.

Here is my code:

```
program MDBtoMySQL;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, odbcconn, db, sqldb;

var
  ConnMDB, ConnMySQL: TODBCConnection;
  QueryMDB, QueryMySQL: TSQLQuery;
  TableExists: boolean;
  MDBFileName, MySQLHost, MySQLDatabase, MySQLUsername, MySQLPassword, MySQLTable: string;

begin
  // Set the file path of the MDB file
  MDBFileName := 'motor-0.mdb';

  // Set MySQL connection details
  MySQLHost := 'localhost';
  MySQLDatabase := 'TestingSQLConnection';
  MySQLUsername := 'root';
  MySQLPassword := 'Areva123';
  MySQLTable := 'new_table';

  // Create MDB connection
  ConnMDB := TODBCConnection.Create(nil);
  ConnMDB.Driver := 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)';
  ConnMDB.Params.Add('DBQ=' + MDBFileName);
  ConnMDB.LoginPrompt := False;

  // Create MySQL connection
  ConnMySQL := TODBCConnection.Create(nil);
  ConnMySQL.Driver := 'MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver';
  ConnMySQL.Params.Add('SERVER=' + MySQLHost);
  ConnMySQL.Params.Add('DATABASE=' + MySQLDatabase);
  ConnMySQL.Params.Add('USER=' + MySQLUsername);
  ConnMySQL.Params.Add('PASSWORD=' + MySQLPassword);
  ConnMySQL.LoginPrompt := False;

  try
    // Connect to MDB
    ConnMDB.Connected := True;

    // Connect to MySQL
    ConnMySQL.Connected := True;

    // Check if the table already exists in MySQL
    QueryMySQL := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
    QueryMySQL.Database := ConnMySQL;
    QueryMySQL.SQL.Text := 'SHOW TABLES LIKE "' + MySQLTable + '"';
    QueryMySQL.Open;
    TableExists := not QueryMySQL.IsEmpty;
    QueryMySQL.Close;
    QueryMySQL.Free;

    // Create a new table if it doesn't exist
    if not TableExists then
    begin
      QueryMySQL := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
      QueryMySQL.Database := ConnMySQL;
      QueryMySQL.SQL.Text := 'CREATE TABLE ' + MySQLTable + ' (field1 int, field2 VARCHAR(255))';
      QueryMySQL.ExecSQL;
      QueryMySQL.Free;
    end;

    // Retrieve data from MDB
    QueryMDB := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
    QueryMDB.Database := ConnMDB;
    QueryMDB.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM your_table_in_mdb';
    QueryMDB.Open;

    // Populate data into MySQL
    QueryMySQL := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
    QueryMySQL.Database := ConnMySQL;
    QueryMySQL.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO ' + MySQLTable + ' (field1, field2, ...) VALUES (:field1, :field2, ...)';

    QueryMDB.First;
    while not QueryMDB.EOF do
    begin
      QueryMySQL.ParamByName('field1').AsString := QueryMDB.FieldByName('field1').AsString;
      QueryMySQL.ParamByName('field2').AsString := QueryMDB.FieldByName('field2').AsString;
      // Add more parameters for other fields as needed

      QueryMySQL.ExecSQL;
      QueryMDB.Next;
    end;

    // Cleanup
    QueryMDB.Close;
    QueryMDB.Free;
    QueryMySQL.Close;
    QueryMySQL.Free;

    // Disconnect from the databases
    ConnMDB.Connected := False;
    ConnMySQL.Connected := False;
  finally
    // Free resources
    ConnMDB.Free;
    ConnMySQL.Free;
  end;
end.
```

I also have checked all my drivers to make sure they are installed properly:

Does anyone know where I might be going wrong? I am frustrated that I keep getting the same result no matter what I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Although the error message sounds differently I'd first check the way the Access db is opened: `ConnMDB.Driver := 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)'` refers to the 32-bit Access driver. This works in a 32-bit application only, i.e. you must have installed the 32-bit application of Lazarus. Did you? Or did you install the 64-bit version? In this case you would have to use the `'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)'` driver.